# what's the difference between dom of jquery and "native" dom?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have some result like this:

```
1. //node, root are "native" dom object from getElementById and alike
2. $(node)[0] == node //true
3. $(root)[0] == root //true
4. node.parentNode.parentNode == root //true
5. $(node).parent().parent()[0] == $(root)[0] //true
6. $(node).parent().parent() == $(root) //false
```

I want to write some code like line 6, which doesn't work. So I have to use line 5 instead.Why doesn't line 6 work?

To my knowledge, jQuery dom is the container/wrapper of "native" dom. May anyone explain the details or recommend reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one DOM.

But when you build `$(domObject)` you're making a new jquery object encapsulating a dom object.

There is no reason for this object to be equal to another `$(domObject)` even if the domObject is the same.

Look at it like this : `new ProxyObject(a) == new ProxyObject(a)` would return false because `new ProxyObject` builds an object. That's the same problem with the prettier syntax of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Why line 6 return false is because they are two different object.

`$(root) == $(root)` return `false` too.

For the same dom element `root`, every time you do `$(root)` produces a new jQuery object.